# Can Ubuntu budgie 17.04 be run on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B?

Tags: pi-3

Can Ubuntu budgie 17.04 be run on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B? I see quite often people only running Ubuntu mate on them. I really like budgie though. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

No only a limited number of ubuntu versions can run on the Pi including but not limited to mate, kubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, and ubuntu-server these are the only versions that can run on the Pi as they are the only versions of ubuntu compiled for the specific arm architecture the Pi uses.

Comment: mate is not the only version of ubuntu that can be run on a pi...

kubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, and ubuntu-server can also run on a pi.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the tip I'll be sure to edit that into my answer